# Perl : Error during installion of a module of CPAN

Tags: perl, csv, installation, rdf, cpan

I run on Mac OS X 10.5 and I want to write a program in Perl. However, I need to install the module [RDF::Trine](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/RDF::Trine) and [DBD::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/DBD::CSV) and I got an error when I install both.

If I write :

```
install RDF::Trine
```

The error is :

```
Files=51, Tests=5,  2 wallclock secs ( 0.21 usr  0.18 sys +  1.30 cusr  0.51 csys =  2.20 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 49/51 test programs. 5/5 subtests failed.
make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 2
  /usr/bin/make test -- NOT OK
Running make install
  make test had returned bad status, won't install without force
```

And the error for the installation of DBD::CSV is :

```
Files=21, Tests=18,  1 wallclock secs ( 0.10 usr  0.08 sys +  0.85 cusr  0.26 csys =  1.29 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 16/21 test programs. 2/18 subtests failed.
make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 255
  /usr/bin/make test -- NOT OK
Running make install
  make test had returned bad status, won't install without force
```

Do you have a solution for me?

Comment: Could you post the full test output? It's a bit hard to tell what's wrong without that output.

Comment: I'd like to answer to you request. However, now when I enter something in the cpan shell, I've this error : 

Argument "yes" isn't numeric in numeric ge (>=) at /Library/Perl/5.8.8/Term/ReadLine/readline.pm line 2192.         

And the program crashs...

Do you know the reason of this?

It could be because I ran 2 process of CPAN and he asked me some strange questions...

Comment: Do you have any idea why my program cashs?

Answer (score 2):

Can you post the output of:

```
cpan RDF::Trine
```

or even

```
cpan Bundle::CPAN
```

A **LOT** of perl developers develop on MacOS.  I'd be surprised if it didn't work out of the box.

Updated, easier to read cpan output here than in a comment.  It looks like your cpan is set to ignore dependencies:

```
---- Unsatisfied dependencies detected during ----
----     GWILLIAMS/RDF-Trine-0.125.tar.gz     ----
    Text::Table [requires]
    DBD::SQLite [requires]
    XML::LibXML::SAX [requires]
    Unicode::Escape [requires]
    Unicode::String [requires]
    Text::CSV [requires]
    Error [requires]
    Test::Exception [requires]
    Test::JSON [requires]
    XML::Namespace [requires]
    Data::UUID [requires]
    Math::Combinatorics [requires]
    Set::Scalar [requires]
    XML::CommonNS [requires]
    XML::LibXML [requires]
    JSON [requires]
    Log::Log4perl [requires]
  Ignoring dependencies on modules ARRAY(0x4d22268), ARRAY(0x5463770), ARRAY(0x4d1bbe4), ARRAY(0x4d22724), ARRAY(0x4d21fc8), ARRAY(0x4d226c4), ARRAY(0x4d21fa4), ARRAY(0x5463830), ARRAY(0x5463878), ARRAY(0x4d24cf0), ARRAY(0x4d22784), ARRAY(0x4d21f74), ARRAY(0x4d21f5c), ARRAY(0x4d21e3c), ARRAY(0x4d21ee4), ARRAY(0x4d21d4c), ARRAY(0x4d21e84), ARRAY(0x4d21c80), ARRAY(0x4d21efc), ARRAY(0x4d2219c), ARRAY(0x4d21fb0), ARRAY(0x4d2213c), ARRAY(0x4d21ddc), ARRAY(0x4d2264c), ARRAY(0x4d21ed8), ARRAY(0x5463818), ARRAY(0x4d21d94), ARRAY(0x4d22640), ARRAY(0x4d21de8), ARRAY(0x4d1bb00), ARRAY(0x4d21c98), ARRAY(0x4d2225c), ARRAY(0x4d21f68), ARRAY(0x4d22334)
```

[`prerequisites_policy`](http://search.cpan.org/~andk/CPAN-1.9402/lib/CPAN.pm#Config_Variables) is the configuration variable that controls this behavior.

Confirm the setting by running `o conf prerequisites_policy` and if it's set to anything other than `ask`, run:

```
o conf prerequisites_policy ask
o conf commit
```

(Those are lowercase letter "oh")

Then repeat your cpan commands.

Comment: /usr/bin/tar: Read 4608 bytes from -
RDF-Trine-0.125/bin/rdf_transcode.pl
CPAN: File::Temp loaded ok (v0.22)
---- Unsatisfied dependencies detected during ----
----     GWILLIAMS/RDF-Trine-0.125.tar.gz     ----
    ExtUtils::MakeMaker [build_requires]
  Ignoring dependencies on modules ARRAY(0x3148da4), ARRAY(0x3148cb4)
never reached at /Library/Perl/Updates/5.8.8/CPAN/Distribution.pm line 667.

This is only the end because stackoverflow don't allow me to post more...

Comment: If I apply the sudo cpan Bundle::CPAN, Ive an error :

  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 2 tests but ran 0.
t/04_pwhich.t (Wstat: 512 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Non-zero exit status: 2
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 4 tests but ran 0.
Files=7, Tests=14,  0 wallclock secs ( 0.04 usr  0.03 sys +  0.14 cusr  0.04 csys =  0.25 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 2/7 test programs. 0/14 subtests failed.
make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 255
  ADAMK/File-Which-1.09.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:

Comment: Downvote for teaching `sudo cpan`. This is not a good idea at all because the tests run with root privileges. Instead, they should be used only for installing into system locations. [`make_install_make_command` and `mbuild_install_build_command`](http://p3rl.org/CPAN#Config_Variables) exist for this reason.

Comment: @daxim - Sorry about that.  I've been doing it like that for *years*.  does the cpan command default to using sudo if it's available automatically?

Comment: @user376112 -- you can post that output as a new answer, to your question, or edit your original question to include this output. It'd be easier to read in those cases than as a comment.  However -- from the snip you did paste, it looks like you also need ExtUtils::MakeMaker.  Try installing that via cpan, then retry your original list.  cpan is *supposed* to be able to track this and do it for you, so something is not quite kosher here.

Comment: Undid downvote after edit. No, CPAN does not default to using `sudo` if available. If you want this improvement, you can write up a patch: https://github.com/andk/cpanpm

Comment: My output is too long for stackoverflow. I've uploaded my output file at this URL : http://rapidshare.com/files/412708777/outuptRDF.txt

It's for the command : cpan RDF::Trine

thanks for your help

Comment: Thanks again for your answer. The problem is the same as I told before. My cpan shell is crashed. If I try to execute a command inside, I've an error. For example, If I apply your command, I've this : 

cpan[1]> o conf prerequisites_policy askArgument "yes" isn't numeric in numeric ge (>=) at /Library/Perl/5.8.8/Term/ReadLine/readline.pm line 2192

Do you know the cause of this problem?

Comment: Try manually editing /System/Library/Perl/5.8.8/CPAN/Config.pm (this is the path to the file on my MacOS 10.5 PPC machine)

Comment: After you correct that problem, you may want to re-install Term::ReadLine ASAP to correct the readline problems.

Comment: The path is correct. However, I've no such file in thedirectory /System/Library/Perl/5.8.8/CPAN. Do I have to create this file? If yes, could you show me the content of your file?

Thanks

Comment: could I see the content of your file?

Comment: @user376112 - sorry, I vanished for a few days, and I didn't have my mac booted up (it's a slow G4 1ghz :-/)  I've dumped my config @ http://pastebin.com/TZFqiph1 , it's good for the next month.

Answer (score 0):

You can install perl module forcefully

> ## perl –MCPAN –e’force install “RDF::Trine”’

Where **RDF::Trine** is the module name